# Swift: Go to other view controller after Google Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, gidsignin

After users successfully signing in, I want the screen to show the tab controller view automatically.

Now I finished the integrating Google Sign In part. But after signing in, the view return to the initial View Controller.

My storyboard looks like this, the blue View inside the initial View Controller is the Google Sign In button.

[image]

Below's my `didSignInFor` function:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

I know I should add codes in `else{}`, but still not sure how to do.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use the navigation controller to push the forwarding view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case first of all you need to create a class for your `UITabBarController` which will confirm `UITabBarController` not `UIViewController` something like:

```
class TabBarConroller: UITabBarController {
```

`TabBarConroller` is your new `.swift` file. Now go to your storyboard and click on your `TabBarController` and click on Identity Inspector and assign this newly created class to it.

Next you need to initiate that class if user successfully authenticate with below code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarIdentifier") as! UITabbarController
self.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And one more thing you need to assign in `Storyboard ID` from Identity Inspector which will be `TabbarIdentifier`.

So your code will look like:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
      withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarIdentifier") as! UITabbarController
        self.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, since my `didSignInFor` function is in AppDelegate.swift, which doesn't include the `self.present` member, so I use: `self.window?.rootViewController?.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)` instead of your last line of codes.

Comment: You dont need to add it in Appdelegate because as you have showed it's different viewcontroller you are using in your storyboard

Comment: You can add `didSignInFor` to your viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having this problem, I used this code to redirect to a different view controller:

```
    // redirects to signed in user view controller
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "User_Feed_View")
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController? = vc
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I used this in appDelegate inside the didSignInFor sign function, and it seems to work.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
      if let error = error {
        if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
          print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
        } else {
          print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return
      }
      // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
      let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
      let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
      let fullName = user.profile.name
      let givenName = user.profile.givenName
      let familyName = user.profile.familyName
      let email = user.profile.email
     
        
        
        // redirects to signed in user's view controller
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "User_Feed_View")
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController? = vc
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var loginType : String = ""
var tokenFb : String = ""
var email : String = ""
var googleName : String = ""
// Google Integration

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {

        self.loginType = "gmail"
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        tokenFb = user.userID // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        googleName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        email = user.profile.email

        if user.profile.hasImage
        {
            let imageUrl = signIn.currentUser.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 150)

            image = (imageUrl?.absoluteString)!
            print(" image url: ", image)
            self.profileURL = image
        }
        self.loginSocialAPI()
    }
}
```

self.logSocialApi() is the API through which I can login and in that api need to set the path of particular viewController.

Comment: Hi, I don't have the loginSocialAPI() in my AppDelegate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need to put this code in appdelegate 
i think your Google Sign in button is in ViewController class.